# The fast & effective way to display bitmap in the window?

Tags: c++, image, qt, opengl, bitmap

I am developing a soft that plays sequences of images in given frame rate.

The key feature of this kind of soft is to display images very fluently without any lags.

So far I used these techniques to display bitmap data in window:
1. earlier I was used only strict **Windows API** and I used BitBlt() function in WM_PAINT: case
2. later in **QT** version I used label->setPixmap() function

I am not happy with QT results, I think it was not playing in real time that BitBlt was.

So, should I use for ex. OpenGL and texture funcions to have really fluenty results?
Is BitBlt the most efficient method? Do you have some advices? I don't want to use some very high level additional libraries (except OpenGL)

One more thing, the player should play 1920x1080 resolutions images fluently, and have the ability to play even larger images if the hardware parameters are strong enough.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If this is a game.. OpenGL. You can test using WinAPI with a Real-Time-Message-Loop (PeekMessage). Ex: http://www.directxtutorial.com/Lesson.aspx?lessonid=9-1-4  If you aren't happy with the results, use OpenGL then.

Comment: Research "double buffering" and "multiple buffering".  These concepts should speed up your program.

Comment: No, it's not a game, it's Windows application...

Comment: Windows BitBlt actually is not very efficient. That's why DirectX from version 3 onward (3 was the first version actually published) provided functions for direct graphics memory writes. In X11 the XV extensions serves similar. OpenGL can be used for fluid animation playback, if the right method of uploading the images to the GPU are used.

Comment: @datenwolf: can you tell something more about direct graphics memory writing in DirectX, what should I looking for?

Comment: Ok, I think that using Direct2D will be good choice, I am developing my soft under Windows, and Direct2D is hardware accelerated for displaying things like bitmaps etc...